# The film will already be started by the time we get to the cinema

Tags: grammar, phrase-choice

Could you please tell me whether the selected sentence

> We are late. **The film will already be started by the time we get to the cinema**.

is grammatically correct?

Comment: It's *grammatically* "correct", but *idiomatically*, native speakers would almost always say *...will already **have** started...* (which is equally "correct") in contexts like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my native dialect, ***have*** would be used instead of ***be***, there. We tend to use present perfect when using verbs like *finish*, *start*, and so on as verbs in the usual way. *Finished* is generally recognised as being an adjective as well as the past participle of *to finish*, but we usually use it as a verb, too. There are dialects where it's normal to say something *is finished* rather than *has finished*, and that's perfectly grammatical by any standard - and we use the adjective for some things, like completing a task rather than a film or playing ending.

Some authorities allow for the use of *to be* in forming a present perfect when using the passive voice and an intransitive verb, like the Christian greeting at Easter:

> He **is** risen.

By those standards, "the film will already be started" is a passive construction, and grammatical. This is more common in some dialects than others.

In all the dialects that I have good familiarity with, "the film will already **have** started" is more idiomatic. The use of *be* would be sufficiently strange to many people, so that they might consider it wrong, even though some formal grammars would say it is not ungrammatical - and whether people think you're wrong is often more important than whether you are wrong by some reference standard.

Comment: Thank you very much! You answer is great! But it covers quite a lot of topic quite briefly. Could you please make it a little more detailed? 1) I'd like to know the rationale behind the preferring the present perfect for the verbs start and finish 2) what are those things (like completing a task rather than a film or playing ending) when you use adjective and what are the things when you don't use adjective 3) Do you mean that "He is risen" may mean "He has been risen" and "the film will already be started" may mean "the film will already has been started" by those standards?